# Create a route named '/query' and send response as explained above when this route is requested

Tags: node.js, express

Complete the body-middleware file and `app.js` file in the given application such that, all the query parameters required by the route are validated and null and undefined values 
throw an error message -

```
{error: true, status: 403, userMessage: 'some query parameter missing',
    data: <Name of the parameter that is missing>}.
```

The query parameters that are compulsory are - `name :String`, `age:Number`

On Success, display the following response -

```
{error: false, status: 200, userMessage: 'all query parameters entered',
    data: {name: <Name passed in query params>, age: <age passed in query params>}}.
```

Note:Check for body params using if-else and then use the `next()` function or `res.send(errorObject)` accordingly.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete, what I could get from this is that when http://someweb.com/api/query is being accessed if anything in query has undefined/null it should through error. ex: http://someweb.com/api/query?name=abc&addr=null.

Comment: Is it correct what I understood from your question or it is something else you are looking for?